# Finding a symmetric matrix E such that the approx eigenpair for A is the exact eigenpair for A+E

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a real $N\times N$ matrix.
If $(x^TAx, x)$ is an approximate eigenpair for $A$ ($x$ a normalised vector)  then find a symmetric $E$ such that $(x^TAx, x)$ is an exact eigenpair for $A+E$.

Just can't figure out how to go about this. Thanks for any insight,

Beans x

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. Can you explain what you have tried? What do you know about these concepts?

Comment: Hi and thanks. I tried E= -Ax(xT) + (xT)Axx(xT) but this didn't get me anywhere because I don't know if A is symmetric, also considered somehow using the symmetric component of A ((A + AT)/2) but couldn't see how to do that if it's even the right idea. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r:=Ax-\rho x$ with $\rho:=x^TAx$ and $x^Tx=1$. If $E:=-(xr^T+rx^T)$ (clearly $E$ is symmetric), then 
$$(A+E)x=Ax-(r^Tx)x-(x^Tx)r=Ax-(r^Tx)x-r.$$ 
We have $r^Tx=(Ax-\rho x)^Tx=x^TAx-\rho x^Tx=0$ so
$$
(A+E)x=Ax-r=\rho x,
$$
that is, $(\rho,x)$ is an eigen-pair of $A+E$.